# Object of std:: class cannot be converted to string

Tags: php, echo, json, var-dump

Below is a sample json code that I want to access...This json is actually coming from an API. Whenever I copy and paste the entire json in json lint..It says valid json..

```
foreach ($movies as $movie) {
echo "theaters ".var_dump($movie->release_dates->theater)";
}

//Im actually trying to access a nested json in php... Something like
{
"movies":[{
"tile":"Cowboys";
"release_dates":{"theater":"2013-11-29"}, 
so on....
```

Whenever I try to write the above it gives me an error `Object of stdclass cannot be converted to string` ....Or if I write

```
$x = json_decode(var_dump($movie->release_dates->theater), true)";
echo "theaters "$x[0];
```

It gives an output like `string[10]:2013-11-25 string[10]:2013-11-30`....So on..What is the error....

Comment: `var_dump` doesn't return anything, so it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: To expand on @Barmar's point, `var_dump` is for outputting debug info to yourself, not parsing JSON.

Comment: Actually I want to print tile, release_dates where this json response is coming from an API.. I have used curl to send the request and response..Im able to print tile by looping through as in the above code like foreach($movies as $ movie){ echo"$movie->tile";} This is printing the response successfully.But I am unable to retreive the date for the release_dates in the json..How do I do it??

Comment: Please post the output of `var_dump($movie)`

Comment: It gives an output of everything..All the unformatted data in the page when I say var_dump($movie)...Like object(stdClass)#2(12){["title"]=>string(24) so on

Comment: To make things simpler...This is the code I have..

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode($movies, true);

foreach ($data as $movie) {
   echo "theaters ".implode(', ', $movie->release_dates->theater)";
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've got an unterminated string constant there.

Comment: It is giving an error like json_decode takes one parameter as string, array given